# On click of each row,corresponding row data should get print in Angular js

Tags: html, css, angularjs

1. Hello friends, I am new in angular js.I need help to print the each
   row's data on click of button assigned to each row. Below is my
   code.

   HTML code:

   - List item

   enter code here

   ```
   <div class="jumbotron">
     <table border='1'>
       <tr ng-show="reports.length!=0" ng-repeat="report in reports">

         <td>{{report.first_name}}</td>
         <td>{{report.emp_id}}</td>
         <td>{{report.month_calendar_days}}</td>
         <td>{{report.pay_days}}</td>
         <td>{{report.paid_days}}</td>
         <td> 5" ng-repeat="key in noAlphabetSortPlease(report)" style="padding-left:10px;">{{report[key]}}</td>
         <td><button ng-click="PrintRow()">Print Row</button></td>
       </tr>

     </table>
   </div>   </div>
   ```

   Controller Code:

   angular.module('app', [])

   ```
   .controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope,
   $filter) {
       $scope.noAlphabetSortPlease = function(obj){
         return Object.keys(obj);
       }
        $scope.reports = [{"emp_id":"10001","first_name":"siva","status":1,"month_calendar_days":29,"pay_days":29,"paid_days":21,"salary_head_value1":0,"salary_head_value2":7550,"salary_head_value3":1600,"salary_head_value4":1800,"salary_head_value5":345,"salary_head_value6":6400,"salary_head_value7":5000,"salary_head_value8":31955,"salary_head_value9":1250,"salary_head_value10":12000,"salary_head_value11":6000,"salary_head_value12":47900,"salary_head_value13":15945,"salary_head_value14":4000,"salary_head_value15":2400},
   {"emp_id":"10002","first_name":"naren","status":1,"month_calendar_days":29,"pay_days":29,"paid_days":21,"salary_head_value1":15501,"salary_head_value2":7551,"salary_head_value3":1601,"salary_head_value4":1801,"salary_head_value5":346,"salary_head_value6":6401,"salary_head_value7":5001,"salary_head_value8":31957,"salary_head_value9":1251,"salary_head_value10":12001,"salary_head_value11":6001,"salary_head_value12":47907,"salary_head_value13":15950,"salary_head_value14":4001,"salary_head_value15":2401},
   {"emp_id":"10003","first_name":"Bhaki","status":1,"month_calendar_days":29,"pay_days":29,"paid_days":21,"salary_head_value1":15502,"salary_head_value2":7552,"salary_head_value3":1602,"salary_head_value4":1802,"salary_head_value5":347,"salary_head_value6":6402,"salary_head_value7":5002,"salary_head_value8":31959,"salary_head_value9":1252,"salary_head_value10":12002,"salary_head_value11":6002,"salary_head_value12":47914,"salary_head_value13":15955,"salary_head_value14":4002,"salary_head_value15":2402}];


     $scope.PrintRow=function($index){          window.print();
               }   }]); </script>
   ```

Comment: You don't need the ng-show, and on the line above the ng-click it looks like something's missing.

Comment: try it with ng-repeat-start + ng-repeat-end

Comment: that does not matter..i have added button to each row.when user click any row,corresponding row should get print..

Comment: Already each row is getting printed in the table. What exactly is it that you want to print and in what format?

Comment: suppose if i click print button of first row,then only first row should get print ,not all. and same for other rows also

Answer (score 2):

Pass the corresponding object to the function call and overide your reports variable.

```
<tr ng-show="reports.length!=0" ng-repeat="report in reports">

      <td>{{report.first_name}}</td>
      <td>{{report.emp_id}}</td>
      <td>{{report.month_calendar_days}}</td>
      <td>{{report.pay_days}}</td>
      <td>{{report.paid_days}}</td>
      <td> 5" ng-repeat="key in noAlphabetSortPlease(report)" style="padding-left:10px;">{{report[key]}}</td>
      <td><button ng-click="PrintRow(report)">Print Row</button></td>
    </tr>


  $scope.PrintRow=function(obj){   
    $scope.reports=[];
    $scope.reports.push(obj);
            }
```

Or If you want all data to persist and want to print the corresponding data of each row below the new table.Then you could do something like this

```
<tr ng-show="reports.length!=0" ng-repeat="report in reports">

      <td>{{report.first_name}}</td>
      <td>{{report.emp_id}}</td>
      <td>{{report.month_calendar_days}}</td>
      <td>{{report.pay_days}}</td>
      <td>{{report.paid_days}}</td>
      <td> 5" ng-repeat="key in noAlphabetSortPlease(report)" style="padding-left:10px;">{{report[key]}}</td>
      <td><button ng-click="PrintRow(report)">Print Row</button></td>
    </tr>
```

{{newArray}}

```
$scope.newArray=[];
  $scope.PrintRow=function(obj){   
    $scope.newArray.push(obj);
            }
```

Format new array to your desire.

```
  <tr ng-show="reports.length!=0" ng-repeat="report in newArray">

      <td>{{report.first_name}}</td>
      <td>{{report.emp_id}}</td>
      <td>{{report.month_calendar_days}}</td>
      <td>{{report.pay_days}}</td>
      <td>{{report.paid_days}}</td>
      <td> 5" ng-repeat="key in noAlphabetSortPlease(report)" style="padding-left:10px;">{{report[key]}}</td>
      <td><button ng-click="PrintRow(report)">Print Row</button></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Just one more help.When i am clicking Print button of first row,then 2nd and 3rd rows not displaying...

Comment: So you are telling that if I click the correspond print button of a row, all data should persist but only the corresponding row should be printed ?

Comment: You just have to pass the corresponding object to the print function and capture the value in a new array. Then you can populate this new array in a new table or div below your existing table in whatever way you desire. Hope this is what you are looking for?